# Change Element Order CSS - Weird Case

Tags: css

How can I achieve the effect below using only CSS?

[image]

My current Code

```
<div>
        <h4></h4>
        <img>
        <p>
</div>


@media (min-width: 550px) 
{           
        img {float: left; width: 300px;}
}
```

***EDIT:*** apologies for the confusion, but currently my code keeps the h4 element on top of the image after floating it. I want to move it to the side as shown in the figure. The text needs to wrap around the image when it is too long.

Comment: Could you put up a working snippet and describe what the problem is. 'Weird case' doesn't tell us what is going wrong.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, but currently my code keeps the h4 element on top of the image after floating the image. I want to move it to the side as shown in the figure.

Comment: Can you change the order of HTML elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using float and media query.

```css
.card-container {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
}
.card-header {
  font-family: verdana;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

@media (min-width: 550px) 
{           
  .card-container {
    border-color: red;
  }
  .card-header  {
    float: right;
    width: calc(100% - 210px);
  }
  .card-img {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  }
}


.clearfix::before,
.clearfix::after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.clearfix::after {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-container clearfix">
  <h4 class="card-header">This is header</h4>
  <img class="card-img" src="https://picsum.photos/200/200">
  <p class="card-desc">1Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam tenetur eum dignissimos esse dolorum dolorem quia quaerat voluptates ullam, qui dolor quod hic incidunt ab ipsum, architecto pariatur in repellendus.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: But what if I don't know the size of the image?

Comment: In that case you can repeat card-header for small and big screen and show or hide depending using media query.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) for that. Just add a two column layout with two rows for the right column like that:

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}

h4 span.variation--big {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightgreen;
  }
  .two-col-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-template-areas: 
      "image text_top"
      "image text_bottom"
    ;
  }
  .two-col-grid img {
    grid-area: image;
  }
  .two-col-grid h4 {
    grid-area: text_top;
    margin: 0 0 0.5em 0;
    padding: 0 1em;
  }
  .two-col-grid p {
    grid-area: text_bottom;
    margin:0;
     padding: 0 1em;
  }
  h4 span.variation--small {
    display: none;
  }
    h4 span.variation--big {
    display: inline;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="two-col-grid">

  <h4>
    <span class="variation--small">Small</span>
    <span class="variation--big">Big</span> Screen
  </h4>
  
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/134/1600/900">
  
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want my text in the paragraph to wrap around the image. I need to make float work somehow.

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect the desired behaviour ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the float

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
}

@media (min-width: 550px) {
  img {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
  }
  xmp {
    float: right;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h4>
    <xmp>
      <h4>Small Screen</h4>
    </xmp>
  </h4>

  <img src="https://pics.freeicons.io/uploads/icons/png/9023038671580097531-512.png">
  <xmp>
    <p>Text goes here</p>
  </xmp>
</div>
```

Comment: What if I don't know the width of the image?

Comment: The exact width of the image does not matter. When set to 200 px ,That is, the image is displayed in 200 px